# How come BeautifulSoup is returning None?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following Python script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.ncaa.com/game/3518260/play-by-play'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

game = soup.find(id='gamecenter-tab-play-by-play')

print(game)
```

Which is producing 'None' when I run it.

[image]

This is the inspection of the websites code:
[image]

Can someone explain to me why the code is failing to find the div that I am point to? I have also tried with .find_all but that is not working either.

Thank you for your time and if there is anything I can supply to help clarify, please let me know.

Comment: `game = soup.findAll("div",  {'class': 'gamecenter-tab-play-by-play' })` returns the div you're seeking. However it returns an empty list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python). You're searching by id but your element shows a class. But if the data is injected with JS, you won't get the data you want by requesting and parsing the HTML even with the correct DOM name. You'll need a tool like Selenium or make a request to the JSON endpoint that the page is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above comment by [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen) is the answer you are looking for.

If you want to scrape using selenium you need to download driver for your browser.

ex: if you want to use chrome you can get the chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

> Note: get the same version as your current browser or it won't work

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

    def get_scraped_data():
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,
                              executable_path=<chrome driver path>)
        driver.get(url='https://www.ncaa.com/game/3518260/play-by-play')
        values = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(values, 'html.parser')
        game = soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'gamecenter-tab-play-by-play'})
        return game
```

If you want to run the pop up window in background you can use the below option to the driver

> chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')